# Pandas - Check if a column contains a substring of a string

Tags: python, pandas, series

Let's say I have this example Series ser:

```
ser = pd.Series(["gmail", "yahoo", "office"])
```

and the following string:
`t = "mail@mail.com"`

I want to check if any of the values in the Series is a substring of the string t.

For the other way around it's very easy (ser.str.contains(t)), but what's an efficant way to do my way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
any(s in t for s in ser)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` or `all`:

```
any(x in t for x in ser)
```

```
all(x in t for x in ser)
```